# Верстка тянущейся во все стороны рамки со сложными краями

Tags: вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте! Не подкажете пример реализации на css рамки с неровными краями, тянущейся по горизонтали и вертикали? (При растяжении повторяется средняя прямая часть). 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набросал примерно:

```
<style>
#cloud{
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
left: 2px;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
}
#topLeft{
position: absolute;
top: -2px;
left: -2px;
width: 100px;
height: 2px;
background-image: url(адрес картинки);
}
#topRight{
position: absolute;
top: -2px;
right: -2px;
width: 100px;
height: 2px;
background-image: url(адрес картинки);
}
#bottomLeft{
position: absolute;
bottom: -2px;
left: -2px;
width: 100px;
height: 2px;
background-image: url(адрес картинки);
}
#bottomRight{
position: absolute;
bottom: -2px;
right: -2px;
width: 100px;
height: 2px;
background-image: url(адрес картинки);
}
#left{
position: absolute;
top: -2px;
left: -2px;
height: 100px;
width: 2px;
background-image: url(адрес картинки);
}
#right{
position: absolute;
top: -2px;
right: -2px;
height: 100px;
width: 2px;
background-image: url(адрес картинки);
}
<style>
<div id = "cloud">
<div id="topLeft"><!-- Верхняя левая рамка --></div>
<div id="topRight"><!-- Верхняя правая рамка --></div>
<div id="bottomLeft"><!-- Нижняя левая рамка --></div>
<div id="bottomRight"><!-- Нижняя правая рамка --></div>
<div id="left"><!-- Левая рамка --></div>
<div id="right"><!-- Правая рамка --></div>
<!-- А здесь контент -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[background-size](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size)

Должно решить вашу проблему установка background-size:cover;Теперь фон на всю высоту блока